# Convention for reporting 95% confidence interval for 100% success proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, reporting, clinical-trials

In a clinical trial, if a successful endpoint is achieved by the entire population, what is the convention for reporting the exact confidence interval?

Eg, if 50/50 achieved success would it be most suitable to report "100%, 95%CI 92.9-100.0%" Or some other convention?

Comment: Of possible interest: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

Comment: First, I doubt "population" is the correct term. As a rule, population is something you don't have full access to and deduce its properties from a sample. And, if so, why would you report a confidence interval at all? CI should give you information about the "real" population, estimated from the sample. So what's the point of your CI? "If we'd keep repeating this trial into infinity, we'd expect 92.2 - 100.0% of the probands to achieve the endpoint." What is purpose of this evaluation? To show that your trial design leads to high percentage of reaching the endpoint?

Comment: my apologies - the sample. This is a subgroup comparison for gender. We wanted to use the CI to compare across the two groups - the sample of women is larger (eg, 148/150 (99%, 95%CI 95.3-99.8%). So we wanted to comment on the width of the intervals